# Macbook Pro early 2011 Thunderbolt to USB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, usb, thunderbolt

I am looking into expanding my Macbook Pro's USB ports as I only have one USB port working and I have tried everything from resetting SMC and PRAM, firmware updates, etc.

Using a USB hub from the remaining USB port is not really an option as I use it for my Traktor Pro 2 Soundcard

I have been looking around for a Thunderbolt to USB hub/dock but they are quite expensive.

I was thinking will a Thunderbolt to FireWire adapter, Then Firewire to USB work?

If not, are there any other options in expanding the USB ports without using the last remaining USB port?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Traktor Pro 2 Specifications page](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-audio-interfaces/traktor-audio-2/specifications/), doesn't have any requirement that the USB port must be bus powered or host only.  In fact, they even state there is an optional Power Supply available:

[image]

So, the PS is only required if you can't get the 5V .5A from the bus (host).  In this case you have a couple of options

- Use the Power Supply
- Use a powered hub

As for going Thunderbolt to Firewire then to USB, I am a proponent of using the "right tool for the job."  Can you do it?  Yes.  But it's a bodge.<sup>1</sup>

Insead, go directly from TB to USB with a  [Thunderbolt to USB adapter][2]

[image]

Finally, you never did say why your USB connector doesn't work nor which one. In my experience, it could be a very inexpensive fix to repair the connector.  This is definitely something you should look into.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Bodge:*  *Verb. 1. To do a poor job or repair. 
2. To cobble (something together). E.g."I bodged together that furniture out of driftwood and old egg boxes."* [From A Dictionary of UK slang.](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/b.htm)

Comment: There is no practical need to use a cropped screen shot for the power supply info and waste bandwidth when plain text is all that's needed!

Answer (score 0):

In your question what did you mean by: *Using a USB hub from the remaining USB port is not really an option as I use it for my Traktor Pro 2 Soundcard*.

I can't think of any reason why using a USB hub would be a problem? If it's a concern about power requirements then there are many powered USB hubs available.

As for a Thunderbolt to FireWire adapter and then a FireWire to USB adapter, this should work.

However, if it was me I'd go with a powered USB hub.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been looking around for a Thunderbolt to USB hub/dock but they
> are quite expensive.

Yes, indeed they are, and they are not likely to get cheaper.  There is not a lot of market now for these devices and it's only getting smaller.  Economy of scale is not in your favor.

> I was thinking will a Thunderbolt to FireWire adapter, Then Firewire
> to USB work?

No, that's not likely to work.  First is because I have yet to see any FireWire to USB adapters.  Second, even if they did exist FireWire is not required to provide power to the connected device, the most common FireWire (400 Mbps) has less bandwidth than USB 2.0 (480 Mbps), and the fastest FireWire standard (3 Gbps) is slower than USB 3.0 (5 Gbps).  If it is power or bandwidth you are running out of from USB then FireWire will likely come up short too.

> If not, are there any other options in expanding the USB ports without
> using the last remaining USB port?

Not really.

There's the option of buying Thunderbolt or FireWire devices to replace your USB devices.